# Python: Taking mean over many rows and fixed column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2D array created using Numpy:

```
>>d=np.random.randint(0, 100, (4,5))
  d=array([[19,  7, 22, 73, 84],
           [ 1, 78, 49, 99, 25],
           [43, 97, 17, 83,  1],
           [98,  1, 81,  4, 82]])
```

Let's assume each row corresponds to a particular time while each column corresponds to particular frequency. I need to average two rows for every column and store it in a new array y[2][5]. Eg y[0][0]=average(19,1), y[1][0]=average(43,98), y[0][1]=average(7,78) and so on.

I am trying something like this for averaging:

```
for i in range(0,len(d)/2):
    for j in range(0, 5):
        r1=2*i
        r2=2*(i+1)
        y[i][j]=np.mean(d[r1:r2][j])
```

However it shows:

```
y[i][j]=np.mean(d[r1:r2][j])
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

Any suggestions for using np.mean in a right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just slice the array into two 2x5 arrays, then take the mean in each column of the two arrays and use `vstack` to put them back together:

```
>>> np.vstack((d[:2].mean(axis=0), d[2:].mean(axis=0)))
array([[ 10. ,  42.5,  35.5,  86. ,  54.5],
       [ 70.5,  49. ,  49. ,  43.5,  41.5]])
```

---

Your error occurs because you are using `d[r1:r2][j]` to create a subarray of `d` with two rows and then trying to access a row in that subarray with an index greater than 1 (I think you intend to access columns with `j`).

You need to replace that code with `d[r1:r2, j]` for it to work, but I'd encourage you to make use of NumPy methods rather than Python `for` loops.